# Concept result differs from its content

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Currently I'm learning how to use concepts and I stumbled upon a problem.

I created a simple concept that checks whether operator[] exists for a type.

```cpp
template<typename T>
concept Iterable = requires(T const& A)
{
    A[0];
};
```

Then I created concept that checks if operator[] exists and that it returns a type with a specific size.

```cpp
template<typename T, uint8_t Size>
concept IterableWithSize = requires(T const& A) {
    Iterable<T>;
    requires sizeof(decltype(A[0])) == Size;
};
```

I tested it with `std::string` as `std::cout << IterableWithSize<std::string, 1>;` expecting `1` but for some reason output was `0`.

So I decided to check concept's content separately (I assume logic is the same):

```cpp
std::cout << (Iterable<std::string> && sizeof(decltype(std::declval<std::string>()[0])) == 1);
```

And output for this was `1`

I guess I'm missing something about concepts but could't find information about this.

I'm using Visual Studio 16.11.1 if that's important.

### UPDATE

I changed the code based on suggestions and found that code works as intended without `decltype()` in second concept. However, if we explicitly specify the type in concept itself it starts to work with `decltype()` too.
There's [link](https://godbolt.org/z/W83s8b37x) to the minimal example that shows the problem.

So the question is, is it intended behaviour? And if so, why?

Comment: Not highly relevant, but `sizeof(decltype(A[0]))` is an exercise in redundancy. `sizeof` was always able to examine expressions. So `sizeof A[0]` is sufficient and more readable.

Comment: oddly enough, not reproducible. Could be that `std::string` in your case  have characters with size greater than 1?

Comment: Did you include `<string>` during the first test? Or just `<iostream>`?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Thanks for the info! Actually, if I remove the decltype() from second concept it starts to work as intented and `IterableWithSize<std::string, 1>` returns `1`, interesting. However I still don't understand why.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Not explicitly, but I think `<string>` was included through `<sstream>`

Comment: Don't assume. Always include what you use. The standard library may include forward declarations internally, and not the complete types. And coincidentally, your concept fails (as it should) on incomplete types.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I understand that I missed include and should have included `<string>`, I just was trying to say that it doesn't work with decltype and works without regardless of explicit `#include <string>` (I added it but all stayed the same)

Comment: I can't comment on code I can't see. Please understand the we (i.e. people, the source of bugs that is separated from our programs by the keyboard) are sometimes really bad at retracing our steps when failures are involved. We often times disregard a detail that seems irrelevant, which in actuality is the whole source of the problem. There may be other issues (again I don't see what you try offline), but I felt it important to emphasise this oft overlooked yet usual source of such errors.

Comment: "*There's link to the minimal example that shows the problem.*". This is obviously a [bug](https://godbolt.org/z/Wevh9z8E9) of MSVC.

Comment: @康桓瑋 Oh, didn't even think to check other compilers. That answers the question then, thanks. Maybe you'll type an answer and I'll mark it as answered?